Segmentation fault disappears after renaming a function
I have a project that was running fine until some updates happened (MacOS and rustc).
Some calls to a library written in C (called from Rust) result in a segmentation fault:
println!("TEST");
unsafe { some_C_func(); }

The output is four times "TEST", but none of the printf's in some_C_func are actually invoked after the println! (Rust) is invoked four times (even though it is written once) the program aborts with a segmentation fault; it is as if the C function was never called.
My best bet is either incompatibilities between toolchains (although that seems like a stretch). Otherwise I would think perhaps Undefined Behaviour in Rust could cause this?
I am looking for possible issues that could cause something like this to happen.
reproducible example
window.h:
void* window_window(void*);

window.c:
// takes a pointer to a struct defined in this library
void* window_window(void* ptr) {
    printf("WINDOW IN C\n");
    return ((Window) ptr)->glfwWindow; // return a value of type *GLFWWindow
}

The Rust project contains a build script that generates rust bindings given window.h (using bindgen)
so in rust the mapping looks like:
extern "C" {
  fn window_window(arg1: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void) -> *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void;
}

This code is then called from an implemention on a struct:
struct Window {
  ptr: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
}
impl Window {
  fn window(&self) -> *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void {
    println!("WINDOW");
    unsafe {
      window_window(self.ptr)
    }
  }
}

The output (upon calling Window::window once) is
WINDOW
WINDOW
WINDOW
WINDOW
zsh: segmentation fault  cargo run

The C library links to (all static) GLFW, metal, and cocoa, Dear Imgui. They are linked (or compiled into, in case of ImGui) into a dynamic library.
the problem also occurs with a similar function which returns int (instead of a pointer) and is named window_update.
MacOS Senoma 14.5
The old rust version I cannot find, the new version is the latest: stable-aarch64-apple-darwin (rustc 1.82.0).
Rust projects are assembled using cargo, for C I use XCode (for any metal related programming) and CMake.

is the C function you're calling sufficiently uniquely named? If a different library you link against has the same name then it could call that one instead (where a mismatched signature could easily cause a segfault)

What is the actual spelling of some_C_func()?  Please make an MCVE (Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example
— or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE (Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example
— the same idea by a different name).  Also, identify the versions of macOS and Rust where the project worked and where it now fails.  At least identify the current (failing) versions. If a library has a symbol with the same name as your some_C_func() but the two symbols don't have the same behaviour, a crash is perfectly possible.

Thank you both for the suggestions, I added a minimal example, the project is quite large, so please let me know if you need anything else.
What puzzles me is that WINDOW is printed four times before a seg fault occurs, this makes me belief there is something seriously wrong on the assembly level.

@kmdreko Do you mean that by chance the same symbol might be defined twice? Could that also explain why the println! from rust (WINDOW) is invoked 4 times? it seems peculiar.

Why do you use println("WINDOW"); instead of println!("WINDOW");? And, why not println!("WINDOW\n");?

Pls show the C typedef for Window as well as the requisite struct definition.

@Plegeus As to why the print happens 4 times, if there is undefined behavior invoked, the behavior is... well... undefined. The print call running 4 times is just one of the infinitely many possible outcomes. Trying to reason about UB is futile; by definition, you cannot reason about it.

@CraigEstey that is a typo. I will fix it in an edit.

Indeed the answer is that there are multiple definitions for the same symbol. Thank you all for the help!

The problem is indeed a double definition.
Within the library the same function is defined twice (window_window in this case).
More specifically it was defined within a C library as shown above, but also within the rust project as follows:
    #[no_mangle]
    unsafe extern "C" fn window_window(handle: *const ()) -> bool {
      println!("THIS IS NOT GOOD");
      /* snip */
    }

The #[no_mangle] attribute makes it so the name is preserved in the binary, hence there are two definitions.
